# Creating a view that shows multipule blocks containing content with filtered by differnt taxonomy terms

Tags: views, theming

Im looking to create some pages that contain blocks of content based on a separate taxonomy term for each block.

Right now i created a separate block view for each taxonomy term, and added each view into its own block on the block administration page. (http://cs.scottrlarson.com/services)
It works, but I want to have more control over the container of the set of blocks as a whole so I can style the blocks in a flexbox. I wondered if there was a way to create a view that had different blocks filtered by taxonomy terms for each block that way I could set a style name for the container of the blocks allowing me to use flexbox styles.

If anyone has a better way to do this please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a parent `block` view that has all of the subsequent views as `attachment` display type.  Or add the other views in the footer of your first view...

Comment: This worked, but Im having a problem getting the flexbox to wrap the items. Right now it shows the flex items in a vertical column instead of displaying the flex item divs in a horizontal row.  I searched high and low for the css in the developer tool thats breaking the flex behavior and I cannot find the css that is causing the problem. Im using bootstrap as my main with a sub-theme attached. any help would be appreciated. Here is the new test view I am working with : http://cs.scottrlarson.com/services-view

Comment: apply flexbox to the `.attachment` element not `.view`

Comment: OK thanks, that is working.. any idea why the divs are not equal heights?

Comment: Never mind I think i figured it out. some how divs are being stacked at the bottom that are not apart of the view, I have to find out why those are being displayed.